# Keep div at the bottom of another div - css

Tags: css

© 1965 - 2010

I want the #copyright to be at the bottom of #outer

Here is the css for #copyright

```
#copyright{
    position:relative; margin-bottom:0px; width:672px; height:20px; color:#FFF;
}
#yr{
    margin:auto;
}

#f{ position:absolute; right:0px; text-align:center;
}
```

Thanks
Jean

Answer (score 77, accepted):

```
#copyright {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
#outer {
    position: relative;
}
```

This will have the unfortunate side effect though that `#copyright` does not count towards the height of `#outer` anymore, in your example `#outer` would be 0px high. You can add a bottom-padding to `#outer` if you're working with fixed heights.

```
#copyright {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 200px;
}
#outer {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 200px;
}
```

Comment: everything goes out of way, I would appreciate if you could provide me a solution for #copyright....thanks in advance

Answer (score 9):

1. define height of #outer
2. set #outer to position:relative;
3. set #copyright to position:absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0;

```
    #outer {
      height: 100px;
      border: 1px solid red;
      position: relative;
    }

    #copyright {
      position:absolute; 
      height: 30px; 
      bottom: 0; 
      left: 0;
      border: 1px solid black;
      width: 300px;
    }
```

```
    <div id="outer">
       <div id="copyright">
           <span id="yr">© 1965 - 2010</span>
           <span id="f"></span>
           <span id="d"><span>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Also, never use "0px". There is no such thing as zero pixels, only zero. Correct way is "right: 0;"

Answer (score 3):

I would do that this way:

```
#copyright {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
}
#outer {
position: relative;
height: 200px;
}

<div id=outer>


<div id="copyright">
    <span id="yr">&copy; 1965 - 2010</span>
    <span id="f"></span>
    <span id="d"></span>
</div>



</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the positioning on `#copyright` to absolute and add a relative positioning context to `#outer`.  Then add `bottom: 0px` to `#copyright` as well.

Sorry.  CSS would look like:

```
#copyright{
   position:absolute; margin-bottom:0px; width:672px; height:20px; color:#FFF; bottom: 0px;
}
#yr{
   margin:auto;
}
#f{
   position:absolute; right:0px; text-align:center;
}
#outer {
   position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KwmMyb :

```css
#outer_div {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#inner_div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer_div">
  <div id="inner_div"></div>
</div>
```